# Cannot access iron-ajax object in the script part

Tags: html, ajax, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have the following code.
The chrome console says following:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined

i installed iron-ajax, platform, polymer, promise-polyfill and webcomponentsjs through bower.

i never programmed with polymer. 
what could be a possible mistake? something with the imports?

> master-mind.html

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html" />
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html" />

<dom‐module id="master-mind">
    <style>


    </style>

    <template>
        <iron-ajax
            auto
            id = "ajax"
            handle-as = "json"
            method = "get"
            last-response="{{createCodeResponse}}"
            debounce-duration="300">
        </iron-ajax>
        <textarea rows="1" id="actual_code" style="width: 490px;" readonly="readonly" value="{{createCodeResponse}}"></textarea>
        <br />
        <textarea rows="10" id="messages" style="width: 490px;" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="message" size="60" />
        <input value="Send" onclick="check();" type="button" /> 
    </template> 

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is : "master-mind",

            ready: function() {
                this.$.ajax.url = "http://localhost:8080/KSWE_7_1/resources/mastermind/";
            }

        });
    </script> 

</dom‐module>
```

> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
<title>MasterMind</title>
<script src='js/jquery.js'></script>
<script src='bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js'></script>
<link rel='import' href='master-mind.html' />
</head>

<body>
    <br />
    <master-mind></master-mind>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you able to access some other element? Try `console.log(this.$.message)` in the `ready`-event and see if that works.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined`   nope.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it asynchronously in the attached method as follows:

```
attached: function(){
  this.async(function(){
    this.$.ajax.url = "http://localhost:8080/KSWE_7_1/resources/mastermind/";
  },someTimeIfThereAreManyItemsToLoad);
}
```

#### Edit

I don´t know where is your error, but this code works:

```
 <dom-module id="master-mind">
    <template>
      <iron-ajax
            auto
            id = "ajax"
            handle-as = "json"
            method = "get"
            last-response="{{createCodeResponse}}"
            debounce-duration="300"></iron-ajax>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "master-mind",  
            ready:function(){
              this.$.ajax.url = "http://localhost:8080/KSWE_7_1/resources/mastermind/";
              console.log(this.$.ajax.url);
            },
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: nope. did't help. actually tried that one at the begin. but tried again now and nope....

Comment: I made a copy of your element, this code should work.

Comment: i don't know what was wrong. but i think the mistake had something to do with the fact i copied example code from a PDF file which was written on windows. i use linux. because i typed everything in a different code editor. and it just works. it is really weird. but it works...thanks for your help.